# 301 Redirect Dynamic HOST includes DOCUMENT_ROOT

Tags: mod-rewrite

Based on what I read on Apache I used the following example they provided to do a 301 Redirect on all my web sites.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This is not quite working as they said it would. If I try www.domain.com it works. If I try domain.com I get www.domain.com//home/www/public_html/www.domain.com

Looks like it wants to include the DOCUMENT_ROOT in the redirect. Am I better off to create an individual .htaccess for each web site?

What is faster to run - Apache or HTACCESS?

Comment: what other rewrite rules do you have in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: I do have any at this time. I just wondering if I should go that direction see the results I am getting now using `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead. Make sure you include the `RewriteBase /`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

If you still get the old result, [your previous 301 redirect is probably cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules/9204355#9204355), retest in Private (Incognito) Browsing Mode.

Comment: That `RewriteBase /` was the missing ingredient. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Using Apaches `httpd.conf` is faster since accessing the `.htaccess` file adds a small overhead—Apache checks every directory—and parent directory—for the file and it will be loaded for every request.

Using the `httpd.conf` is better when you have access to it. Use `.htaccess` if you don't have access to the main configuration file.

Comment: Will stick with `httpd.conf` I do have access. Any reason why it would include the DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: You need to add `RewriteBase /` or a leading `/` if you're using redirects not inside a `<Directory>` block.